# Cannot deactivate num key anymore

Tags: numlock

Somehow I pressed accidentally a key combination such that the 'num key' was always activated (the light on the num key was always on). I could not find a way to deactivate the num key afterwards. Furthermore the keyboard was not working anymore. I had to turn off the computer by keeping the turn on button pressed for a longer time.

Since this happened now for the second time could you tell me how I can avoid this? Is there any key combination which I can press to deactivate the "permanant activated num key"?

Comment: It is impossible to solve this problem without more details. It may also be a hardware problem. Please edit your question and add details like what key combination you pressed? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using any extra or special add-ons or software? Does the problem happen if you reboot the computer? Does it happen in Windows (if dual booting)? Does it happen if you boot from the Ubuntu installation USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option?

Comment: I don't know the key combination when it happened. I use ubuntu 20.04. It does not happen when I reboot the computer only if I press the key combination (which I unfortunately don't remember)